# Safari seems to cache the page and the DOM state

Tags: javascript, safari, greasemonkey, userscripts, ninjakit

I've written a Greasemonkey javascript that works fine in NinjaKit the new Safari userscript manager, but when I try and compile the same script using the Safari 5 extension builder I get some very weird behavior.

The script gives the user an options editing screen, when you click the save button, the script saves the users preferences as a JSON packet via the HTML5 localstorage API, the script then closes the options screen and reloads the page, on the page reload, the script should reload the preferences from the JSON in localstorage, and the script should act on the new preferences to display the page the way the user wants it according to the settings they made.

The problem I am seeing is when I run it as an extension, when I click the save button, the script reloads the page, but when the page is reloaded the changes the user made to the settings do not get applied to the page. the weird part is, if I then manually reload the page again via the browsers refresh button, the changes the user made in the settings do all of a sudden become apparent. so obviously the data has been saved to the localstorage, but for some reason when the page reloads for the first time, it's somehow being reloaded from a cached file, and only on the second manual reload, is the new page displayed correctly. I can't understand why this works as a plain userscript in ninjakit, and also actually works in Firefox, Opera and Google chrome, it just wont work as an extension in safari, its soooo annoying. I've tried lots of ways to make sure that Safari 5 doesn't reload a cached page, e.g adding extra parameters to the URL, but I just can't get it to work, without having to reload the page twice.

BTW I'm not using the native safari extension settings system as I want the script to be cross browser compatible, so that's why I'm saving the settings to localstorage.

Has anyone else witnessed this behavior? Or got any clues how to fix this? It's driving me mental...

Comment: Tags do not belong in the question's title.  QuantumSoup's edit was a major improvement, and subsequent edits were just extraneous comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i managed to solve the problem though i didnt figure out exactly what was causing it.

i got the script working by adding it as an "end script" rather than a "start script" in the extension builder, it all seems to work fine now. phew!